# SQL Server 2012 & SSIS - need to get the Microsoft.SQLServer.DTS.Design.DLL

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, ssis

I need to get the `Microsoft.SQLServer.DTS.Design.DLL` in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies` folder installed somehow.

I installed almost everything possible, like Data Tools for Visual Studio 2012, SQL Server BI, Client SDK etc. but it is still missing.

What do I need to install?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at this link ? http://arcanecode.com/2015/01/07/sql-server-ssis-ssdt-error-method-not-found-microsoft-sqlserver-dts-design-visualstudio2012utils-isvisualstudio2012proinstalled/